# Fatal error: Call to undefined function stream_context_create()

Tags: php

As far as I can tell `stream_context_create()` should always be available and defined.  What could cause this?

Comment: Are you using [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)?  ***i.e.*** it's always in the [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) scope: `\stream_context_create()`

Comment: @Digigizmo I went to look into your question (I'm not using namespaces btw) and the problem seems to have resolved itself. I'm not sure how or why, though I think it had something to do with using copy / paste and getting some strange not printable characters into the code. I had that problem with some other code I found online.

Comment: Just had the exact same thing happen to me in Notepad++. The black (not blue) syntax highlighting should've been a dead giveaway!